# Firebase return internal server error

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm using firebase functions. And there is a problem. I deployed my functions source to firebase yesterday. It was working source and serviced well util today. But right now! suddenly returns internal error and not logging it(Firebase doesn't show internal error in firebase logger i don't know why). I didn't edit my source and it was not difficult code.

This is my code.

```
exports.keyboard = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

    responseMessage = {"type" : "buttons", "buttons" : global.defineManager.MAIN_BUTTONS}

 response.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(responseMessage))
});
```

And this is what i received.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
        <title>500 Server Error</title>
    </head>
    <body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
        <h1>Error: Server Error</h1>
        <h2>The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
            <p>Please try again in 30 seconds.
            </h2>
            <h2></h2>
        </body>
    </html>
```

I'm using firebase blaze price. What should i do? What am i wrong?

Comment: If you have obvious and unexpected errors coming from Firebase products, you should contact Firebase support. firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features

Comment: @DougStevenson oh i didn't know that. ok i will report issue next time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a problem on firebase itself, not yours. Currently they are reporting a service outage. 
https://status.firebase.google.com/