# Firebase Error: HTTP Error: 500, Internal error encountered

Tags: html, firebase

As hosting website in firebase I am getting following error : Error: HTTP Error: 500, Internal error encountered.

Comment: @KyleWilliamson Though the error code is the same, this is not the same issue as what you linked to. It is an outage, while the linked issue was apparently caused by a coding mistake of the developer.

Answer (score 2):

If you use multiple web sites in Firebase, you need to click "Add another site" in the Hosting section.

[image]

Only after this operation the "HTTP Error: 500, Internal error encountered" will go away during hosting deployment.

Answer (score 1):

*firebaser here*

There is currently an [outage that is preventing new deploys to Firebase Hosting](https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Hosting/19006). Our team has deployed a fix and the situation should be improving for everyone. For the latest status updates, check the link above.

In general when you have unexplainable behavior, always check the [Firebase status page](https://status.firebase.google.com/) to see if it's an issue that is already known.

Answer (score 1):

You can try update to the newest version of firebase

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

This helped in my case as I was with some older version.

Answer (score 0):

I also encounter the deploy issue minutes ago, and still can not succeed. I've browse several threads on stackoverflow, but not detaily. However, I followed this one to checkout if the problem is caused by Firebase itself:
[Firebase return internal server error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49194297/firebase-return-internal-server-error)

and lead me to "Firebase Status Dashboard"
https://status.firebase.google.com/

It does show that Hosting service is undergoing "Service Outage".
But I'm not sure if it's the cause.